# Update a dynamic ActiveX list box in a Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, listbox, activex

I enter information to my database via a userform. The information from the form goes in to a database in a worksheet called  ”Data”.  I have a Dashboard on a sheet called “Dashboard” with an ActiveX  listbox (called ActiveX_List) populated with data from 10 rows from the Datasheet. 
The listbox is supposed to be dynamic and updated when new data is entered in to the Datasheet, but I can’t get it to work.

If I close down Excel and open it again the listbox updates perfect!. But it’s a bit inconvenient…

I have an offset formula stored I the Name Manager called “ActiveX_List” and the formula is: =OFFSET (DATA!$B$3;0;0;ENGINE!$AJ$5;10)*.
In the ActiveX listbox property the ListFillRange = ActiveX_List (the offset formula from the name manager).

I thought the list would be updated automatically. But now  I assume that some kind of macro must be executed, for example when I hit the ”Save button” in the UserForm.

I don’t understand how to  create a “refresh macro” and I don’t understand where it should be stored and how I should name it so Excel can find it.

I am a newbie to VBA . Help with a code would be great but if someone have time to explain how it work would be even better and very appreciated.

Sincerely
Ulf

*It is taken from YouTube, Tiger spread sheet solutions “Excel Userforms for Beginners (8/10)”)

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the `ListFillRange` like this:

```
Sub RefreshListFillRange
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("ListBox21")
        .ListFillRange = .ListFillRange
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It works perfect! I had never figured out that myself.

Comment: @UlfJohansson Understandable `OLEObjects` can be a pain to work with.  Happy Coding!